# Change style and icon on primefaces calendar

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, styles

I am trying to change the default style on primefaces calendar and tried many solution but still no idea how to change it. For example i want to change the button icon.

This is my calendar in my .xhtml file:

```
<p:calendar id="date_to"  showOn="both" value="#{WebClient.date_to}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
```

And this are  the solution that i tried so far but did not work, still the same default calendar.

Not working solution 1:

```
.ui-icon-calendar {
    background-image: url("../images/calendar.png") !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Not working solution 2 (using chrome and copy element class)

```
.ui-button-icon-left .ui-icon .ui-icon-calendar {
        background-image: url("../images/calendar.png") !important;
        background-position: center center !important;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
```

Not working solution 3 (found that this is probably the button and tried to change its background)

```
.ui-datepicker-buttonpane{
    background: #00CCFF !important;
}
```

If anyone has an working example how to change the default (change button icon, change colors etc) please share it with me.

Comment: there is a small typo in your second try... (a . missing before the last class... And are you sure this is a good selector anyway)

Comment: yeah, thats a typo I just edited it, nice thing to notice, in my css it was fine.

Comment: In your second example remove spaces between classes. For me the style did not apply with them.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the main problem is the location of the image files. I got the CSS working with the below:

```
.ui-icon-calendar {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/calendar.png']}") !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Note: that your images should be in a folder under *"/webapp/resources/images/.."*.